# How could I take multiple outputs and output the leftmost output?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I know that sounds very confusing, but I have a few examples. I want it so that I can flick something like 3 levers and have the output be the leftmost one.

If I flicked the first two, the middle one would turn on, and if I flicked only the right one, the right one would turn on. During this, all of the other ones would be off.

Here are some examples:

[image: example image 1]

[image: example image 2]

[image: example image 3]

I could use either command blocks or survival redstone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a much simpler answer.
The mechanism involves using redstone signal strength.
[image: The Mechanism]

People call it a Redcoder. I can't really explain it, so I'll let this guy do it:

I think he does a pretty good job saying what it's used for and how it works.
Here is a picture of the different layers of the mechanism.[image: Layers]

Thanks for everyone's solutions. I used Bruno Rodrigues in the project I was making.

Comment: I knew about this contraption but couldn't find a way to use it... Welp there it is! It's more compact but I think it end up having more delay.

Comment: Have you finished your project? I'd be interested in taking a look if you don't mind

Answer (score 3):

Here it is the system:

[image]

And here it is, missing one layer:

[image]

I made it so you could loop it and repeat as many times you want. Dark blocks need to not be a transparent block (such as glass or slabs) and need to be there (cannot be missing), light ones can be either and quartz do not matter. There is nothing under the torches that are close to the Lamps.

Basically it's a chain reaction. Because of how repeaters work (Input can only come from one side and output leaves from another point). you came make that the far left turn off all the torches to his right. making them 'unusable'. It would be way easier to make it with commands but I wanted to make survival friendly. If the system looks confusing in any way, I'll gladly post more screenshots. Hope it helps!.

Comment: Activating the leftmost input activates ALL outputs in your circuit, that's not what the asker wanted. They wanted to only ever activate one output.

Comment: Negative. Powering the left most will negate the others. Test it for yourself. All powered (http://prntscr.com/p8hqni), Middle and right most (http://prntscr.com/p8hqq6) ,  Left most and right most (http://prntscr.com/p8hqtk) and Right alone (http://prntscr.com/p8hr00)

Comment: Then the screenshot in the answer is wrong.

Comment: Oh, you removed the top layer, that's why it happens. That's pretty confusing.

Comment: I mean, between images it's said "here it is ,missing one layer". It's fine tho.